# Slack integration with Tekton missing pipeline event messages

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, slack-api, tekton, tekton-pipelines

Following the [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ContinuousDelivery?topic=ContinuousDelivery-slack&interface=ui), I created a Tekton Pipeline and integrated Slack through the tool integration. I also set up an incoming webhook following the Slack [API documentation](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks). Along with configuring the webhook URL, channel, and team name, I checked the pipeline events as shown below. [image]

I have received messages regarding the successful binding between the Tekton pipeline and Slack integration. I am also seeing other tool integrations in the Slack channel but missing the pipeline events like Pipeline start, success, and failure.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is by adding a definition pointing to the [post to Slack task helper](https://github.com/open-toolchain/tekton-catalog/tree/master/slack) and the associated sample.

Additionally, I have to enable the Slack notifications setting under the Tekton pipeline.

I have documented the steps with screen captures in a [blog post here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/integrate-slack-with-tekton-pipeline)